# trying to center formerly absolutely positioned element with margin-left and margin-right

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a `<iframe>` which is originally positioned absolutely with both `right` and `left` properties set on initialization. In a media query, I would like the element to be   centered with `margin-left` and `margin-right` by setting those properties to 0. What I don't understand is that I am successfully able to do it with another div `.contact_form` on the same page which has the same initialization (set to `position:absolute` initially with its `right:` value set ) but I cannot apply to same procedure successfully to my `<iframe>`. Can anybody see why that is?

Here is the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/tfgr2oxs/2/

Notice how `contact_form` becomes centered for the media query 768px to 1023 px but that `iframe` is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a few things...

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
```

here is a quick and dirty version for you to look at:

https://jsfiddle.net/3xt0xg5h/

```
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 550px;
  height: 300px;
  background:blue;
  margin: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {

    iframe {
      background: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Sean. However, I would like the `<iframe>` to, at all other viewports, have the `right:150px;` and `left:auto` values. Basically I would like it to operate functionally in terms of how it responds to viewport changes to be identical to `.contact_form`.

Comment: So you just would give it a right of 150px outside the media query, and then inside the media query you would give it a right of 0.

Comment: I agree with you, however, if you look at `.contact_form` it does not re set its `right` value inside the media query. And yet it still has the desired behavior. It only sets its `left` to zero. When I emulate the css from contact form for `iframe`, it still does not have the desired behavior as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/tfgr2oxs/5/